# How to attach my uploaded vhd to a virtual machine in Azure?

Tags: azure, upload, azure-virtual-machine, vhd

I have uploaded successfully my 1TB vhd (not containing Windows files) to Azure storage.
Now I want to attach it as a second drive to my virtual machine but in the attach list I can find only the "attach an empty disk" option!

I used Add-AzureVhd to upload the vhd file: 
Creating new page blob of size 999653638656...

I linked the storage resource in Cloud Service but the vhd is still not available to mount.

The container of the storage where I uploaded my vhd is the same with the one where C: drive of my VM is saved.
The container access is set to private. 
Will it help if I change it to Public Blob or Public Container?

What else to try?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the PowerShell command `Add-AzureDataDisk`. This should be what you're looking for, as you can specify media location of the uploaded vhd.

Alternatively, in the portal, go to Virtual Machines and navigate to the Disks tab, where you can create a new disk:
[image]

At this point, you can navigate to your uploaded vhd:

[image]

After this is done, the new disk should become available for you to add to a Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

It should show the options to attach (Empty Disk and Existing Disk) as show in this [link from Azure documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/attach-a-disk/#attachexisting).

[image]

Assuming the above not possible for what ever may be the reason, the alternative is

- As the you already claim you are able to see the `Attach Empty Disk`; you can attach a 1 TB disk and download and put the blob contents there.
- You wont be charged for the out-bandwidth as it is all internal

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you used CSUpload and not just pushed the VHD to blob storage.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg466228.aspx

Comment: I have used Add-AzureVhd to upload the vhd file: 
Creating new page blob of size 999653638656...

Comment: It took 3 days to upload with Add-AzureVhd. Is there anything else that I can try before spending other 3 days using CSUpload?

Comment: You don't need `CSUpload`. The `Add-AzureVhd` PowerShell command works just fine.